# Flutter Dart - List<Chat>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Chat'

Tags: flutter, dart

I simply want to add a list to another list.

```
List<Chat> allChats1;
List<Chat> allChats2;

...

allChats1.add(allChats2);
```

But I'm getting: The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Chat'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a **Chat type List** to a **List** that accepts only **Chat** instances.

If you want to add the Chat instances that are in **allChats2** you must use **addAll**, like this.

```
allChats1.addAll(allChats2);
```